# How to link image and text in html?

Tags: html, css

I want to link an image with the text, so when I will resize the window, the text will move with the image. Here is an example [google.de](http://www.google.de/). As you can see the text under the google logo move along with image when resizing the window.

Here what I tried.

HTML

```
<div class="logo"><img src="here is my logo" width="350"></div>
<div class="textlogo">Here is the text</div>
```

CSS

```
.logo
{
    text-align:center;
}
.logo img
{
    position:relative;
}
.textlogo 
{
    position:absolute;
    top:25%;
    left:64%;
}
```

Comment: Did you view the google source? Did you understand how it does it? Did you try to replicate _that_?

Comment: Yes I viewed it but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you in understanding the way ( No rocket science )

http://jsfiddle.net/MVYGd/1/

Answer (score 1):

This is what google actually does

```
<div title="Google" align="left" id="hplogo" style="background:url(images/srpr/logo3w.png) no-repeat;background-size:275px 95px;height:95px;width:275px">
<div nowrap="nowrap" style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:214px;top:70px">Deutschland</div>
</div>
```

You can do it in the same way